# Linux Mint 18.2 and Android

Tags: linux

When I try to install android on Linux, I have to put my password into terminal. When I try to do that, I am not able to type anything. When I try to, nothing will type. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

you wont see the typed password. just type your password and press enter